# Kedushah during silent Shemoneh Esrei

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, bowing-kneeling, kedusha-prayer

I've heard that if you've finished Sim Shalom (or Shalom Rav) when the Chazzan reaches Kedushah, [you should say Kedushah with the Minyan](/q/1061).

If you do say Kedushah, should you bow at Zeh Elzeh Vi'amar or rise on your toes at Kadosh Kadosh Kadosh, Baruch, and Yimloch?

Comment: Who bows at Zeh el Zeh? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44115/759

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1061/759

Comment: It's more about saying the yehi ratzon

Answer (score 2):

In terms of whether you should bow at זה אל זה, that has been dealt with in another post and is dependent on your מנהג but it is by no means obligatory.

About going up on your toes at קדוש x 3, ברוך and ימלוך, the רמ''א quotes (in אורח חיים סימן קכה סעיף ב) from earlier sources to lift oneself from the ground at these points in קדושה so an אשכנזי should definitely do this and I believe the ספרדי minhag is that way too although the מחבר doesn't write it.

If you want to know whether to do these manoeuvers when still in שמונה עשרה after שים שלום, there is no reason for that situation to be any different.